# DOMDocument parsing right way

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have an xml from an exernal server like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response ResponseReference="200002">
    <ResponseDetails Language="en">
        <SearchCurrencyResponse>
            <CurrencyDetails>
                <Currency Code="ARS"><![CDATA[Argentine Peso]]></Currency>
                <Currency Code="AUD"><![CDATA[Australian Dollar]]></Currency>
        </CurrencyDetails>
        </SearchCurrencyResponse>
    </ResponseDetails>
</Response>
```

What is the right way to take all currency (code and text inside)?

I have tried in this way and works but is there a way to make it more fast? Because I can have thousands of elements:

```
$searchCurrencyReponseElements = $xpath->query( 'ResponseDetails/SearchCurrencyResponse', $responseElement );
foreach( $searchCurrencyReponseElements as $searchCurrencyReponseElement ) {
     $CurrencyElements = $xpath->query( 'CurrencyDetails/Currency', $searchCurrencyReponseElement );
     foreach( $CurrencyElements as $CurrencyElement ) {
          echo '<p>Currency: '.$CurrencyElement->textContent.'</p>';
     }
}
```

And how to take the code attribute? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to select all nodes by a specific node name then use [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). Try this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($path);
// get all Currency nodes
$currencyNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Currency');
// iterate over them
foreach($currencyNodes as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('Code') . ' ' . $node->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Perfect works like a charm... I prefered to use foreach because I can have nested array into the xml.. and I don't know how to go inside it... for exampleif I had another "level" inside currency? Like: <CurrencyDetailMore><Language>it</Language><Other>some other</Other></CurrencyDetailMore> (hope you can understand thanks

Comment: Yeah I (think that I) understand. But you made it to complicated. Expressed in `XPATH` it would be `//Currency` meaning select all Currency nodes regardless of their position in tree. But that's the same as `getElementsByTagName()` where the latter is faster

Comment: If foreach currency I want to take its Language inside another node I can do this inside the foreach? $currencyLanguages = $node->getElementsByTagName('Language'); foreach.... I have change $doc with $node is the correct way inside a currency to take its language?

Comment: To make it short: You doing it all wrong :) I cannot give a general answer to this. Take the time and follow some DOM and/or XPath tutorials.